# Invoke C# code from SQL Server Job agent

Tags: c#, sql-server

Is there a possibility of SQL Server Job (that runs every day) to call a C# console application and send this datetime to that console application. I use this datetime to complete the URL parameters like this

```
string startDate = "";---> from sql job agent
string endDate = ""; --> from sql job agent
string inputURL = "https://www.test.com/articles.json?fieldsstartpub_date%5D%5Bgte%5D=" +startDate+ "&conditions%5Bendpub_date%5D%5Blte%5D=" +endDate;
```

Thanks
MR

Comment: Could you not use a scheduled task for something like this on the server as opposed to SQL?

Comment: This is the client requirement